# Is there a way to increase the Visual Studio console history (buffer) length?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, logging, console-application, command-history

Can the Visual Studio console history (buffer) length be increased beyond the build in 32766 lines?

I tried this, but it did not help:

```
Console.SetBufferSize(1000, short.MaxValue-1); 
Console.BufferHeight = short.MaxValue-1;
```

I wanted to avoid using a log file and possibly any libraries.

**Background:** In the last year, I moved to Visual Studio 2022 and Windows 11 (with the newer console). Now it just gives me 32766 lines. That sounds like a lot, but having a million lines is much better when I have lots of output with my simple c# console apps. I used to be able to go to the console properties and update the buffer history to 99999 and the number of buffers to some high also, but now I cannot find that:

[image]

I tried setting the history to a large value in the new Windows console, but it did not help.

[image]

**Update**: it looks like this might be a known issue:

- https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1410
- https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3612

Comment: I assume what you actually want to increase is not the "history size" (number of previously executed commands) but the "screen buffer size" (number of output lines). I don't have Windows 11 in front of me at the moment, but I'd wager the [registry settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc978583(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) are still honored. Although that setting is documented as supporting a maximum of 32767 lines. Are you sure what you claim to have done actually worked in the past?

Comment: @Luke - I tried changing that to 7FFF7FFF (that max value) but it did not help. Thanks for the tip. There was also a HistoryBufferSize in that same area, but it did not help. I think it was the "number of buffers" in the classic. That used to default to something low and can be set to a high value but it is missing now. Also, just noticed this might be a known issue (see edited question above)